# Correct way to style a cell inside a TableView without lagging, scroll issues and dynamic height issues

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a TableView and a cell. The content of a cell is in a UIView. I want to apply this function:

```
extension UIView {
public func addSoftUIEffectForView(cornerRadius: CGFloat = 15.0, themeColor: UIColor = UIColor(red:0.10, green:0.11, blue:0.12, alpha:1.0)) {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize( width: 2, height: 2)
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red:0.08, green:0.08, blue:0.09, alpha:1.0).cgColor

    let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shadowLayer.frame = bounds
    shadowLayer.backgroundColor = themeColor.cgColor
    shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor(red:0.14, green:0.15, blue:0.16, alpha:1.0).cgColor
    shadowLayer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -2.0, height: -2.0)
    shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
    shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 2
    self.layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

to this UIView.

**I have tried the following approaches:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableViewPostComments.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellComment", for: indexPath) as! PostCommentsTableViewCell

    cell.viewTableViewContainer.addSoftUIEffectForView()

    return cell
}
```

*Result: The scrolling of the tableview is lagging, the style is not correct applied while scrolling.*

**Applying the function in my custom TableViewCell:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewTableViewContainer: UIView! {
    didSet {
        viewTableViewContainer.addSoftUIEffectForView()
    }
}
```

*Result: The scrolling of the tableview is lagging, the style is not correct applied because I have dynamic height of a cell. Only the initial cell height is styled.*

What is the correct way to style my UIView inside my TableView cell, without lagging, with correct height, without scroll issues?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `cellForRowAt` will add it multiple times while scrolling in addition to the bounds of the view isn't correct , Do this inside cell custom class

```
var once = true

override func layoutSubviews() {
  super.layoutSubviews()
  if once {
     // add here
     once = false
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sh_Khan, my code looks like this:     var once = true

    override func layoutSubviews() {
      super.layoutSubviews()
      if once {
         viewTableViewContainer.addSoftUIEffectForView()
         once = false
      }
    }. The scrolling laggy, the dynamic height is not applied. Only the initial height.. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a custom class for `UIView()` instead of using an extensive `function()`

- e.g.

```
class RoundAlphaView: UIView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 2
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize( width: 2, height: 2)
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red:0.08, green:0.08, blue:0.09, alpha:1.0).cgColor
        let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shadowLayer.frame = bounds
        shadowLayer.backgroundColor = yourColor.cgColor
        shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor(red:0.14, green:0.15, blue:0.16, alpha:1.0).cgColor
        shadowLayer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -2.0, height: -2.0)
        shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
        shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 2
        self.layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

- And use as `Custom Class`

[image]